# Show that set is a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

I have a measure space $(\mathcal{X},\mathbb{E},\mu)$. I am considering the paving of all $\mu$-nullsets given by:

$\mathbb{N}_{\mu}= \left\{ N \subseteq \mathcal{X} : \exists E \in \mathbb{E} \hspace{0,1cm} \text{such that } N \subseteq E \hspace{0,1cm} \text{and }\mu(E)=0   \right\}$.

I am also considering the paving $E_{\mu}$ which is $\mathbb{E}$ extended by the nullsets:

$\mathbb{E}_{\mu}= \left\{ E \cup N : E \in \mathbb{E} \hspace{0,1cm} \text{and }N \in \mathbb{N}_{\mu}   \right\}$

A paving is understood to be an arbitrary collection of subsets.

I wish to show that $\mathbb{E}_{\mu}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

**My thoughts**

By definition of a $\sigma$-algebra I must show that:

a)

$\mathcal{X} \in \mathbb{E}_{\mu}$

Since $\mathbb{E}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra then $ \mathcal{X} \in \mathbb{E}$.

I have shown that $\mathbb{E} \subseteq \mathbb{E}_{\mu}$. Therefore $\mathcal{X} \in \mathbb{E}_{\mu}$.

b)

If $A \in \mathbb{E}_{\mu}$ then $A^{c} \in \mathbb{E}_{\mu}$.

Assume that $A \in \mathbb{E}_{\mu}$. Then $A$ can be expressed as $A=B \cup N$ where $B \in \mathbb{E}$ and $N \in \mathbb{N}_{\mu}$. Put $E_{1}=B$.

Since $N \in \mathbb{N}_{\mu}$ then there exists a $C \in \mathbb{E}$ such that $N \subseteq C$ and $\mu(C)=0$.

Consider now the union $B \cup C$. Since $N \subseteq C$ we have that $A \subseteq B \cup C$. Put $E_{2}= B \cup C$.

We therefore have that $E_{1} \subseteq A \subseteq E_{2}$ where $E_{2} \setminus E_{1}= C \setminus B \in \mathbb{N}_{\mu}$.

I now have:

$A^{c}=(B \cup N)^{c} = B^{c} \cap N^{c} = (B^{c} \cap N^{c}) \cap (C^{c} \cup C)= (B^{c} \cap N^{c} \cap C^{c}) \cup (B^{c} \cap N^{c} \cap C)$

I am stuck at the last part. I wish to reach the conclusion that $A^{c}=(A^{c} \setminus E_{2}^{c}) \cup E_{2}^{c}$ where $A^{c} \setminus E_{2}^{c} \in \mathbb{N}_{\mu}$ and $E_{2}^{c} \in \mathbb{E}$.

Could someone help me finish the argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A\subseteq E_2$ we have $A^c=(A^c\setminus E_2^c)\cup E_2^c$. Moreover, $$A^c\setminus E_2^c=A^c\cap E_2=(B\cup C)\setminus (B\cup N)\subseteq C\setminus N\subseteq C$$ and thus $A^c\setminus E_2^c\in\Bbb N_\mu$ since $\mu(C)=0$. Clearly $E_2^c$ is in $\Bbb E$ because $B$ and $C$ are in $\Bbb E$ and $\Bbb E$ is closed under union and complement.